# fastest way to check to see if a certain index in a linq statement is null

Tags: c#, performance, linq

**Basic Details**

I have a linq statement that grabs some records from a database and puts them in a System.Linq.Enumerable:

```
var someRecords = someRepoAttachedToDatabase.Where(p=>true);
```

Suppose this grabs tons (25k+) of records, and i need to perform update operations on all of them. to speed things up, I have to decided to use paging and perform the operations needed in blocks of 100 instead of all of the records at the same time.

The code in questions is used in two places: a service method that updates a lot of values in a database, and an integration test that gets the old and updated values to make sure the update was performed correctly.

**The Question**

The line in question is the line where I count the number of records in the subset to see if we are on the last page; if the number of records in subset is less than the size of paging - then that means there are no more records left. What I would like to know is what is the fastest way to do this?

**Code in Question**

```
int pageSize = 100;
bool moreData = true;
int currentPage = 1;
while (moreData)
{
   var subsetOfRecords = someRecords.Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize); //this is also a System.Linq.Enumerable
   if (subsetOfRecords.Count() < pageSize){ moreData = false;} //line in question
   //do stuff to records in subset
   currentPage++;
}
```

**Things I Have Considered**

1. subsetOfRecords.Count() < pageSize
2. subsetOfRecords.ElementAt(pageSize - 1) == null (causes out of bounds exception - can catch exception and set moreData to false there)
3. Converting subsetOfRecords to an array (converting someRecords to an array will not work due to the way subsetOfRecords is declared - but I am open to changing it)

I'm sure there are plenty of other ideas that I have missed.

Comment: "to speed things up, I have to decided to use paging" - why would this speed things up?  Sounds like you are just adding additional work in calculating the page offset each time.

Comment: Is this business logic? A stored procedure would be perfect for this amount of processing...

Comment: what do you mean by paging, what would you create a `stored procedure` and implement `row number` internally ?

Comment: happens in two places:
1:An update method that updates a lot of values in a database.
2:An Integration test that checks to see that all values for some test data were updated correctly.

Comment: Probably a better way is not to grab _tons of records_ in the first place but to implement paging in database (f.e. via `ROW_NUMBER`). Btw, `Enumerable.Count()` is often a good candidate for optimizations since it needs to execute the whole query(again) if it's not an `IList<T>`.

Comment: Some problems: If the number of records is a multiple of the page size, you'll have a last page with zero records.  Also, `System.Linq.Enumerable` is a static class; so `someRecords` cannot be an instance of it.

Comment: @tehdoommarine You may want to try morelinq's [Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - this does seem like a good idea - but I would have to inquire about doing such a thing before I can proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the parallels library. It will handle the paralellezation and paging for you automatically. Is the order that the records are processed in important?

```
var someRecords = someRepoAttachedToDatabase.Where(p=>true); 
Parallel.Foreach(someRecords, record=>DoSomethingWithRecord(record));
```

Comment: when i spoke about this at a meeting i had about this operation, this was actually taken into consideration. i will give this a try.